# Phonegap display notification on specific time every minute even the app is not running

Tags: android, cordova, localnotification

I'm creating an app in Phonegap Android and using LocalNotification plugin from git to show the notification.
Now I have the code:

```
  function onDeviceReady(){
    window.plugin.notification.local.add({
            id:      1,
            title:   'alert',
            message: 'Mesage',
            repeat:  'minutely',
    });
  }
```

With this code, the message will display every minute, but when I go to Setting then Force to Stop, the notification will not appear.
In the future,I want to show a notification in 7:00AM everyday even the app running or not.
Any advise for me to make notification appear when the app is not running.
thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  Force stop makes the app stop permanently.  All alarms and receivers registered in the app will be turned off.  That's the purpose of force stop-  to turn the app completely off.  If you want the app to continue in the background, don't force stop it.